# SageMaker Clarify with imported models

Tags: amazon-sagemaker-clarify

is it possible to use SageMaker Clarify bias and explainability analysis with imported models, like TensorFlow models?Given that the Tensor flow model has been trained from elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. All you need to do is to bring your model to SageMaker in the required model.tar.gz format and host it on a RealTime/ Batch endpoint with Clarify.
Refer to the FAQs on bringing your model to SageMaker [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/hosting-faqs.html)